# facelets.viewhandler Error Rendering View NotSerializableException: eu.jakubiak.jpa.translator.Translator$TranslatorProxyMethodInterceptor

Tags: java, jsf, jboss, seam, language-translation

I'm working on fixing a bug with a previously existing application using:

- Java 6
- JBoss 4.2.3 GA
- JBoss Seam 2.2.0 GA
- JSF2

The application leverages this library for translation

http://code.google.com/p/jpa-translator/

http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/WikiSyntax#Introduction

Are you familiar with this error when trying to post a property of an entity bean to a JSF view?

```
ERROR [facelets.viewhandler] (http-...) Error Rendering View[/public/answer.xhtml]
java.io.NotSerializableException: eu.jakubiak.jpa.translator.Translator$TranslatorProxyMethodInterceptor
```

I my code had this

```
<c:forEach var="_d" items="#{indicatorValuesDimension}">
<s:div styleClass="answer-dimension">#{_d.key.name}</s:div>
```

Where the *indicatorValuesDimension* is a *java.util.Map*, the key is an *@Translatable* entity bean and *name* is an *@Translate* String property.

But if I do this instead it runs just fine...

```
 <c:forEach var="_d" items="#{indicatorValuesDimension}">
 #{_d.key.name}
```

So the same expression runs fine outside any JSF tag but throws NotSerializableException when used inside a JSF tag.

Has anyone come across this before? Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by switching to

```
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>server</param-value>
```

in my web.xml. Using

```
<param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
<param-value>client</param-value>
```

was causing the problem because many classes in the library (BeanReflector?, TranslatorProxyMethodInterceptor?, etc) do not implement java.io.Serializable.